# How to document metaclass members in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, metaclass

I would like to document the metaclass members of a class because those are basically class methods and class attributes.

Here's a minimal example:

```py
"""Module docstring

.. autosummary:
   :toctree: _autosummary

   Foo

"""

class MetaFoo(type):
    """Foo metaclass"""


    def foo(cls):
        """Foo class method"""
        return "foo"


    @property
    def x(cls):
        """x class property"""
        return 42


class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
    """Foo class"""


    def bar(self):
        """Bar method"""
        return "bar"
```

I'm using `autosummary`, so I tried the following as my `_templates/autosummary/class.rst`:

```
{{ objname }}
{{ underline }}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. autoclass:: {{ objname }}
   :members:
   :special-members:
   :inherited-members:
   :undoc-members:
```

But neither the class method nor the class attribute are in the resulting documentation. How can I add the members of the metaclass? I haven't been able to figure out how to access the metaclass in the template. None of the template variables seem helpful to me. Can I perhaps pass the metaclass or its members as custom variables to the template somehow? For instance, if I had `metaclass_methods` and `metaclass_attributes` template variables, I could loop over those in the `class.rst` template. But how can I create and pass these to the template?

Comment: did you ever find a workaround?